# Encontrar el últimos punto en un caracteres en la cadena y elimine todo derecha

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente cadena de caracter `1.2.30`
Quiero encontrar el ultimo `.` y luego eliminar todo a su derecha.

Mi resultado ideal seria `1.2`. Tengo un codigo que me elimina lo ultimo de cadena.

```js
var this_item = "1.2.30".slice(0,-1).trim();
console.log(this_item);
```

Comment: ¡Ya tienes suficiente reputación como para saber cómo funciona el sitio! Si encontraste una solución, ponlo *como respuesta*, no como edición a tu pregunta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Añade la respuesta como respuesta, amig@!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var this_item = "1.2.30";
var punto;
for(let i = this_item.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(this_item[i] == '.'){
        punto = i;
        break;
    }
}
var this_item_sliced = this_item.slice(0, punto);
console.log(this_item_sliced);
```

Básicamente lo que haces es recorrer el string de **manera inversa**, y en cuanto encuentres algún punto, cortas la cadena desde ese índice hasta donde empezaste el recorrido. Cualquier duda me dices! :)

Comment: Gracias x tu explicación, he encontrado la solución ya.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui la solucion

```js
var this_item = '1.2.3';
var lastIndex = this_item.lastIndexOf(".");
var requiredPath = this_item.slice(0, lastIndex + 1);
var this_item = requiredPath.slice(0, -1).trim();
console.log(this_item);
```